# Run a async function without waiting for the response in c# webforms (fire and forget)

Tags: c#, async-await

I have a button that makes a REST request to create a document:

```cs
private void Click(object sender, ActionBaseEventArgs e)
{
   RequestQuotationDocument(quotation.Oid).ConfigureAwait(false);
}

private async System.Threading.Tasks.Task RequestQuotationDocument(int quotationId)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    var values = new 
    {
        DocumentType = "Quotation",
        Id = quotationId.ToString()
    };


    var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(values), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
        "application/json");

    await client.PostAsync(url, content);
}
```

However the page is still waiting for the response of the POST request. How do I make this truly async?

Comment: Does this help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/discards#a-standalone-discard

Comment: You need to make the EventHandler async: `private async void Click(object sender, ActionBaseEventArgs e)` and then await the call to `RequestQuotationDocument`, which _should_ be named `RequestQuotationDocumentAsync`, btw.

Comment: `How do I make this truly async?` what do you really mean? In a web app there's no UI thread, the UI runs on the browser. Web requests are served by a different thread each time. Asynchronous operations are used to save on server threads, not to avoid blocking the non-existent UI thread. If your *browser* makes a blocking call, the browser will have to wait for a response no matter how the *server* handles that request

Comment: To make the browser UI asynchronous you need to use AJAX. WebForms simply wasn't built with that in mind though -AJAX wasn't even called AJAX until 4 years after WebForms were released in 2001. WebForms added asynchronous support through UpdatePanel and other equally convoluted components but these were never as simple to use as the `var response=await fetch(serverUrl);` calls you can do now in JavaScript

Comment: In short, if you want your web UI to be asynchronous, the best option is to abandon Web Forms. Which you should do anyway, that technology was deprecated 10 years ago. If you have a legacy application that can't be updated you'll have to use UpdatePanel and quite a lot of code. Or you'll have to use client-side Javascript to make the async calls and update the DOM elements generated by WebForms, which isn't that easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I make this truly async?

In ASP.NET, [`await` yields to the thread pool, not the client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/october/async-programming-introduction-to-async-await-on-asp-net#asynchronous-code-is-not-a-silver-bullet).

If possible, I recommend changing the client so that a longer request is handled appropriately; e.g., calling this via JavaScript instead of a click handler, and updating the page when it completes.

If you really need to return early from an web request, then you should implement a [basic distributed architecture](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2021/01/asynchronous-messaging-1-basic-distributed-architecture.html). As described on my blog, this consists of two parts:

- A durable queue of work.
- A backend processor of that queue.

Comment: The main problem is WebForms. The only options, UpdatePanel et al or client-side Javascript with DOM updates have several problems. WebForms generates convoluted HTML, mangled IDs and several properties are stored in the view state, so one can't just update it.

Comment: The OP could write HTML and JS that completely bypasses WebForms. At that point though, why not just abandon WebForms?

Comment: Very sad that we can't just fire a task and forget about it when we want this. But if someone knows it's you!